# Insert on duplicate update

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have MySQL table and I need to make query INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE. "id" is primary key, I dont need it for now.

I need to insert values "id2", "name", "city" into the table. If there is some row with the same values in "id2" and "name", then just update "city".
Please where am I wrong ?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 
             `table` 
               (id2, name, city) 
          VALUES 
               ( '$new_id2', '$new_name', '$new_city') 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
               city='$new_city' 
          WHERE 
              `id2`='$new_id2' AND `name`='$new_name'
          ";
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. An `INSERT` statement never has a `WHERE` clause.  It should end after the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Thank you. And how to solve this ?

Comment: You said `If there is some row with the same values in "id2" and "name"` but you ony have `id2` as a primary key. Is `name` intended to be a unique value as well?

Comment: Primary key is ID. It is autoincrement... I can not get ID. I just wanna insert in this table values... If there is some row with "id2" and "name" values, then only update other values - "city" for example....

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood that you have an auto-increment `id` separate from `id2`.  You will need a unique index on the other columns. I can post an answer below.

Comment: I don't have unique index. Unique is just combination id2 + name. I can not change keys in this table. :-(

Comment: If you cannot change the keys to create a new index, then you cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  Note that creating a new index does not require you to eliminate your existing primary key `id`. Do you not have the ability to run `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: I can make some value unique. But it is not unique. Id2 and name are in the table many times. What can not be many times in table, is combination id2 + name. Is there some solution for me ?

Comment: Yes. A key can have 2 columns. If you can create a new index, there is a solution as a multi-column unique index.

Comment: "ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX(`id2`); and "ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX(`name`);   ? Yes, I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you must create an index to enforce uniqueness across the two columns `id2, name` for MySQL to be able to detect duplication. This will create the index with an identifier called `idx_uniq_id2_name`
`

Before you attempt this, you must ensure that you do not already have more than one occurrence of the combination of `id2, name` anywhere in your table. You can verify that with:

```
-- Check for non-unique rows
SELECT id2, name FROM table GROUP BY id2, name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If that returns no rows, you can successfully create the multi-column index.

```
-- Create a multi-column unique index
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx_uniq_id2_name` (`id2`, `name`);
```

After the index has been created, you must correct the syntax of your `INSERT` statement such that it has no `WHERE` clause (which is never allowed for an `INSERT`).

```
INSERT INTO `table` 
  (id2, name, city)  
  VALUES ('$id2', '$name', '$new_city')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE city = '$new_city';
```

Please be advised that your use of variables like `$new_city` in the SQL statement suggest you are not using `prepare()/execute()` with PDO or MySQLi in your code. I would recommend reviewing [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for suggestions on how to improve the situation.